# How can I get intellisense documentation on a curried function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, currying

I've tried every variation I can think of, and I can't get tsdoc strings to show up in the intellisense documentation block for curried functions. Example:

```
/**
 * My outer function--this is documented as expected.
 */
function outer() {
  /**
   * My inner function--this isn't documented.
   */
  return () => 1;
  /**
   * Nor is this:
   */
  const inner = () => 1;
  return inner;
}

// This is where I need the documentation to show up; it should say "My inner
// function--this isn't documented". Every instance of inner has to be manually
// documented.
const assignedInner = outer();
```

I'm not asking how to document *type signatures*; that works fine. The problem is I use a lot of curried functions for dependency injection and the instance of the inner function only has a type signature in the intellisense popup. This can be especially problematic when you have chained or recursively curried functions and the user doesn't get any documentation or examples.